# PHP ceil calculation differs in result from manually calculated result

Tags: php, ceil

I have this script:

```
function round_price_with_limits( $price = null, $multiplier = 9.3, $nearest = 10, $minus = 0.05, $map = 9.95, $msrp = 9999999999) {

    // Ensure a price was provided.
    if ( !empty( $price ) ) {

        // Calculate price with markup and round it.
        $rounded_price = ( ceil ( ( $price * $multiplier ) / $nearest ) * $nearest ) - $minus; 

        // If price is less than minimum, return minimum.
        if($rounded_price < $map){

            return $map;

        }
        // If price is greater than maximum, return maximum.
        elseif($rounded_price > $msrp){

            return $msrp;

        } else {

            // Return price otherwise.
            return $rounded_price;

        }

    }
}
```

It works on almost all products, except for one with $price value = 1,76.
The end result when running the script becommes 9.95
When I calculate by hand, the result is 19.95
Can you spot why this is calculated differently via the php?

Comment: I assume you mean `1.76` and not `1,76` which is quite different. In programming we always work with dots. I have another problem: I cannot reproduce your finding. See: https://3v4l.org/6bPr7

Comment: Passing `"1,76"` does produce OP's result, so that's likely the problem.

Comment: how you calculate by hand using value 1,76. Also when you pass "1,76", it takes only 1 in your calculation discarding all numbers after comma as there is no comma in integers. It should be "1.76" and it will give your desired output

Comment: @prokops Don't ask a question and go offline. Always share an online fiddle link showing a minimum, reproducible example and hang around for a while.

Comment: I appreciate all answers. I did not hang around as I posed the question late evening and I was tired being alone with the kids. I hoped someone would comment so I could move on with the script today. I am an php beginner, so it has been valuable to learn use str_replace. For me, this has been perfect help and I am grateful to all, especially those who spend their time answering stupid questions in a friendly manner.